# Run tasks only on defined number of hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

My goal is to check which servers have any packages waiting for update:

```
- name: yum check | Check for updates
  yum:
    list: updates
    update_cache: true
  register: stat_yum_check_output
```

and then run some tasks +

```
- name: Upgrade all packages, excluding java
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
    exclude: java*
```

on `{{number_of_hosts}}` hosts from among those that returned
`{{stat_check_output.results | length > 0}}`
.

.

.

.

---

old description:

I'm looking for a way to limit run on two different levels.
Righ now I have a playbook that run, against inventory of 50 hosts. One task output is registered in:

```
register: stat_check_output
```

I also have var defined:

```
number-of-hosts: 3   # > 1
```

then I need to play other block/role/whatever ONLY on `{{ number-of-hosts }}` hosts which also matches:

```
when: "stat_check_output.results | length > 0"
```

So far I tried to build a list of host items matching `when` clause, generate new ansible group with add_host module and something else that I forgot already. Any approach so far failed at some point. Each time, the reason was the inability to define something globally.

It looks to me like I'm looking for something similar to `run_once` but with definable counter...

Could someone point me into the right direction, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the feeling you're in an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info). You would probably benefit from giving a bit more background on which kind of tasks you need to run in such a way and the overall goal you're trying to achieve.

Meanwhile, here is an attempt to answer your direct question.

For a task in the middle of other tasks, the below should do the trick.

*Please note that **`number-of-hosts` is an [invalid variable name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names)** for ansible. I replaced it with the valid `number_of_hosts`*

```yaml
- name: "play this on {{ number_of_hosts }} valid hosts"
  vars:
    play_hostvars: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars) }}"
    results_length: "{{ play_hostvars | map(attribute='stat_check_output.results')
      | map('length') }}"
    valid_hosts: "{{ play_hostvars | zip(results_length)
      | selectattr(1, '>', 0) | map(attribute='0.inventory_hostname') }}"
  debug:
    msg: "Do something on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
  when: inventory_hostname in valid_hosts[:number_of_hosts]
```

Note that if your play targets 50 hosts, any tasks your play with those conditions will be skipped on each of them except the matching hosts.

To be more efficient, you could try the following which will create a group of valid hosts and target only the configured number in a specific play:

```yaml
- name: A play targeting all hosts:
  hosts: all

  vars:
    number_of_hosts: 3
  
  tasks:
    # ... previous needed tasks including the one
    # which registers `stat_check_output`

    - name: Tag valid hosts with a fact
      set_fact:
        host_valid: "{{ stat_check_output.results | length > 0 }}"

    - name: "Dynamically add {{ number_of_hosts }} valid hosts to a specific group"
      vars:
        all_valid_hosts: "{{ hostvars | dict2items | selectattr('value.host_valid') | map(attribute='key') }}"
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups:
          - valid_hosts
      loop: "{{ all_valid_hosts[:number_of_hosts] }}"

- name: play targeted only against previously selected hosts
  hosts: valid_hosts
  
  tasks:
    - name: do work to be done
      debug:
        msg: "do something on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Comment: You're right. I have tendency to over simplify descriptions. Description updated.

Comment: It took me a good while to understand what it does :). 
On line 4 `var:`=>`vars:`. 
On line 17 I think `| list` should be on the very end. 


Regardless it doesn't work as expected. I'm getting the same result as I got before with my code. Every host see only itself in `valid_hosts`. 
And everything past "play targeted only against[...]" is played only on a first host in inventory

Comment: 1) you have the same basic powers as all other users here among which editing any question or answer. 2) the above are pseudo examples written on spot and not tested as I don't have an [mre] to play against 3) the `var` was a typo, it's fixed 4) I will not add the `list` since this is only needed if you run ansible 2.9 (or lower) which is deprecated and unmaintained for over 2 years now: upgrade your ansible installation => `pip install --upgrade ansible`

Comment: I fixed a few more typos and both examples are now correct. Here is a [full blown example](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/2453a4b460057bce567060343c9bf0d4) I set up as a [mre] based on the above code snippets.